# "undefined method actions" when attempting to create a form using Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

I'm currently trying to create a form using Active Admin with two boolean properties, as defined next:

```
form do |f|
  f.input :only_active, as: :boolean, label: 'Active Only'
  f.input :include_personal_information, as: :boolean, label: 'Include Personal Information'
  f.actions do
    f.action :submit, as: :button
  end
end
```

However, using this code I'm getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError at ...
undefined method `actions' for #<Arbre::HTML::Form:0x00007fc9c280d778>
Did you mean?  action_items
```

However, according to the [Active Admin](https://activeadmin.info/5-forms.html#default) documentation and the [Formtastic](https://github.com/formtastic/formtastic/wiki) documentation, the "action_items" doesn't exist.

So what I might be doing wrong when creating this form?

Comment: have you tried to wrap inputs inside `f.inputs` block?

Comment: Which version of ActiveAdmin? Is it recent?